# iptables rules for nfs

Tags: linux, nfs, centos-6, scientific-linux

I was getting below error while typing `showmount -e 192.168.56.2` in client machine

```
[root@client ~]# showmount -e 192.168.56.2
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 113 (No route to host)
```

This is my nfs server configuration

nfs server ip 192.168.56.2

This is my nfs share

```
[root@www ~]# cat /etc/exports 
/files  192.168.56.7(rw,sync)
```

These are the two services running in server machine

```
[root@www ~]# service rpcbind status
rpcbind (pid  2626) is running...
```

```
[root@www ~]# service nfs status
rpc.svcgssd is stopped
rpc.mountd (pid 2716) is running...
nfsd (pid 2781 2780 2779 2778 2777 2776 2775 2774) is running...
rpc.rquotad (pid 2712) is running...
```

This is my iptables rule

```
[root@www ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Oct 31 02:08:16 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5:388]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct 31 02:08:16 2013
```

If I flush the iptables rule in server machine then my client is able to see nfs share

```
[root@client ~]# showmount -e 192.168.56.2
Export list for 192.168.56.2:
/files 192.168.56.7
```

That means problem with iptables rule , can anybody tell me what is the problem with my iptables rule , **am I missing any other port ?** How to troubleshoot these types of problems ?

I tried this method from my client machine to verify port is listening or not and this is the output of that

```
[root@client ~]# telnet 192.168.56.2 111
Trying 192.168.56.2...
Connected to 192.168.56.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

```
[root@client ~]# telnet 192.168.56.2 2049
Trying 192.168.56.2...
Connected to 192.168.56.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of open ports for NFS is too restrictive. First, you will have to open the same ports to UDP, then you will need to add 2 more ports. The complete list of ports to be opened is:

```
 sunrpc     111/tcp    rpcbind  #SUN Remote Procedure Call
 sunrpc     111/udp    rpcbind  #SUN Remote Procedure Call
 nfsd-status    1110/tcp   #Cluster status info
 nfsd-keepalive 1110/udp   #Client status info
 nfsd       2049/tcp   nfs      # NFS server daemon
 nfsd       2049/udp   nfs      # NFS server daemon
 lockd      4045/udp   # NFS lock daemon/manager
 lockd      4045/tcp
```

Comment: Before adding 2 ports is there any changes I have to make in this file    /etc/sysconfig/nfs ?

Comment: Not unless you have a non-standard installation.

Comment: According to your answer I changed the iptables rule but 1110 and 4045 ports are still not listening from my client, so I deleted those 2 ports from iptables and added only this 111/tcp, 111/udp, 2049/tcp, 2049/udp and it starts working.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I need some info like by seeing that error how can I guess that its because if port problem ? any log message will provide that info ? or tell me any trouble shooting method.

Comment: Pls accept my answer if it now works. As for troubeshooting: you have connection, you have credentials (you can log in with no firewall), but you cannot connect with firewall. Hence firewall too restrictive. Looked up what I did on another pc. Otherwise, I could have googled needed ports, something like "NFS iptables ports".

Comment: And, BTW, I looked at your ip rules and they were fine, no errors, so only possibility was that you were closing a port needed. Let me add that there is no way to diagnose that, unless you tell iptables to log all connection attempts (and you have not done it). Reason is: remote machine sends connection and thinks: "Everything is OK". Local machine never sees incoming packets, because of firewall. If you want, you can tell iptables to keep a log. Careful: very big file, useful only for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

**NFS SERVER:**

Configure Ports for rquotd(875/udp; 875/tcp), lockd(32803/tcp; 32769/udp), mountd(892/udp; 892/tcp), statd(10053/udp; 10053/tcp), statd_outgoing(10054/udp; 10054/tcp)

```
    vim /etc/sysconfig/nfs
```

If desired, disable NFS v3 and NFS v2 suport by editing lines 5 & 6 of /etc/sysconfig/nfs

```
    MOUNTD_NFS_V2="no"
    MOUNTD_NFS_V3="no"
```

Save current Iptables rules for later use

```
    iptables-save > pre-nfs-firewall-rules-server
```

Flush and check Iptables rules

```
    iptables -F
    iptables -L
```

Stop and Start NFS and related Services in the following sequence

```
   service rpcbind stop
   service nfslock stop
   service nfs stop
   service rpcbind start
   service nfslock start
   service nfs start
```

Make sure the configured NFS and its associated ports shows as set before and notedown the port numbers and the OSI layer 4 protcols. The standard port numbers for rpcbind (or portmapper) are 111/udp, 111/tcp and nfs are 2049/udp, 2049/tcp.

```
   rpcinfo -p | sort -k 3
```

Restore the pre-nfs-firewall-rules now

```
   iptables-restore < pre-nfs-firewall-rules-server
```

Write iptables rules for NFS server (Note: Loopback adapter has to allowed, else you will see packets dropped and also when you restart nfs service, it will spit ***ERROR*** { Starting NFS quotas: Cannot register service: RPC: Timed out rpc.rquotad: unable to register (RQUOTAPROG, RQUOTAVERS, udp). [FAILED] } for rquotad daemon. You can check this by adding a rule with LOG jump target at the bottom of INPUT or OUTPUT chains of filter table)

```
   iptables -P INPUT DROP
   iptables -P OUTPUT DROP 
   iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m multiport --dports 10053,111,2049,32769,875,892 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 10053,111,2049,32803,875,892 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m multiport --sports 10053,111,2049,32769,875,892 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 10053,111,2049,32803,875,892 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -I INPUT  -i lo -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -I OUTPUT  -o lo -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -L -n --line-numbers
```

Configure NFS exports directory

```
   vim /etc/exports 
   exportfs -av
   showmount -e
   rpcinfo -p
```

Stop and Start NFS and related Services in the following sequence

```
   service rpcbind stop
   service nfslock stop
   service nfs stop
   service rpcbind start
   service nfslock start
   service nfs start
```

**NFS CLIENT:**

Save current Iptables rules for later use

```
   iptables-save > pre-nfs-firewall-rules-client
```

Flush and check Iptables rules

```
   iptables -F
   iptables -L
```

Obtain the firewalled NFS Server ports from the client machine and notedown the port numbers and the OSI layer 4 protcols.

```
   rpcinfo -p 'ip-addr-nfs-server' | sort -k 3
```

Restore the pre-nfs-firewall-rules now

```
   iptables-restore < pre-nfs-firewall-rules-client
```

Write iptables rules for NFS client (Note: Loopback adapter has to allowed, else you will see packets dropped and also when you restart nfs service, it will spit ***ERROR*** { Starting NFS quotas: Cannot register service: RPC: Timed out rpc.rquotad: unable to register (RQUOTAPROG, RQUOTAVERS, udp). [FAILED] } for rquotad daemon. You can check this by adding a rule with LOG jump target at the bottom of INPUT or OUTPUT chains of filter table)

```
   iptables -P INPUT DROP
   iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
   iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m multiport --sports 10053,111,2049,32769,875,892 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 10053,111,2049,32803,875,892 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m multiport --dports 10053,111,2049,32769,875,892 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 10053,111,2049,32803,875,892 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -I INPUT  -i lo -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -I OUTPUT  -o lo -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -L -n --line-numbers
```

Stop and Start NFS and related Services in the following sequence

```
   service rpcbind stop
   service nfslock stop
   service nfs stop
   service rpcbind start
   service nfslock start
   service nfs start
```

List NFS Server exports

```
   showmount -e 'ip-addr-nfs-server'
```

Mount NFS Exports manually (persistent mounts can be configured using /etc/fstab)

```
   mount -t nfs ip-addr-nfs-server:/exported-directory /mount-point -o rw,nfsvers=3
   mount -t nfs ip-addr-nfs-server:/exported-directory /mount-point -o rw  --> For NFS4 version
```

Configure autofs, if automounting is preferred for nfs exports and with ldap user home directories (Direct and Indirect Maps can be set)

```
   vim /etc/auto.master    -> specify the mount point and map-name (Eg: auto.nfs)
   vim /etc/map-name
   service autofs stop
   service autofs start
```

Check mounted NFS Exports

```
   df -h -F nfs
   mount | grep nfs
```

List all pseudo root NFS-V4 export directories (NFS Lazy mount)

```
   ls /net/ip-addr-nfs-server
```